# how to set up a jquery promise on a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, promise, jquery-deferred

i have this test case:

```
function setInitialValues (data) {
    window.localStorage.setItem ("name", "some name");
}

var data = '';
$.when (setInitialValues (data)).then (function (data) {
    window.localStorage.getItem ("name"); // this will be 'undefined' instead of 'some name'
});
```

what happens is that `name` doesn't get `set` before i call `getItem`

any ideas how can i solve this?

Comment: There is no need to use promise here... both operations are synchronous here

Comment: also it is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tnXXv/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny i thought so, but for some reason it isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a promise from the method

```
function setInitialValues (data) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    //if some async operation is going on here then to simulate
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.localStorage.setItem ("name", "some name");
        deferred.resolve()
    }, 10)
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tnXXv/)

Comment: do i need the `setTimeout...` function, i want it to go as fast as it takes by default

Comment: @Patrioticcow not really required... it was done so that an async operation is simulated